# Recupera dados com Request.QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma Partial que carrega os dados:

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("PesquisarEventoPorLocal", "CadastroEvento", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                <label for="sel2">Pesquisar Por local:</label>
                @Html.DropDownList("Pesquisa:", ViewBag.TiposLocal as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", id = "comboBox", name= "comboBox" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group  col-sm-3 col-md-3">
                <br/>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Pesquisar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


}
```

No controller não está passando os dados.

```html
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult PesquisarEventoPorLocal()
        {
            string CodigoLocal = Request.QueryString["PesquisarEventoPorLocal"];
            string CodigoLocal1 = Request.QueryString["Pesquisa"];
            string CodigoLocal2 = Request.QueryString["comboBox"];

            return RedirectToAction("index", "CadastroEvento");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem alguns erros no seu código.

Estes campos baixo não existem no seu form, para eles existirem você deve criar um input ou select e adicionar o atributo `name` e definir um nome para o elemento.

> PesquisarEventoPorLocal
>
> Pesquisa
>
> comboBox

Obs: O código a baixo não funciona do jeito que você está esperando

```
@Html.DropDownList("Pesquisa:", ViewBag.TiposLocal as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control", id = "comboBox", name= "comboBox" })
```

Principalmente estes dois atributos:

```
id = "comboBox", name= "comboBox"
```

Quando você cria um `@Html.DropDownList` o primeiro paramêtro é o **id** e o **nome** do elemento, eu ainda não vi como você força o elemento a trocar o id e o nome passado esses dados pelo paramêtro `htmlAttribute`. Por isso que quando você da o *submit* no form você não consegue pegar a query `Request.QueryString["comboBox"];`

---

```
string CodigoLocal2 = Request.QueryString["comboBox"];
```

Este código estará correto se você fizer desta forma:

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
    <label for="sel2">Pesquisar Por local:</label>
    @Html.DropDownList("comboBox", ViewBag.TiposLocal as SelectList,"Pesquisa:", new { @class = "form-control" })
</div>
```

Comment: Agradeço a ajuda

Answer (score 1):

No seu `BeginForm` vc diz que deve submeter os dados para `CadastroEvento`.

Mas na sua controller, vc espera os dados em `PesquisarEventoPorLocal`.

## sugestão de melhoria

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult PesquisarEventoPorLocal(string pesquisarEventoPorLocal, string pesquisa, string comboBox) {...}
```

Comment: pesquisarEventoPorLocal e uma Partial, que carrega os dados, então estou enviando para o CadastroEvento porque a pesquisa e realizada lá, vou testar a sua ideia, agradeço